# Regularity of a Fokker-Planck PDE with unbounded coefficient

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, parabolic-pde, regularity

Let $A$ be a positive definite symmetric matrix, let $b\in C^1(\mathbb R^d\!\times\!(0,\infty))\cap C(\mathbb R^d\!\times\![0,\infty))$ taking values in $\mathbb R^d$. Consider the parabolic PDE
$$ \partial_t \rho(x,t) \,=\, \nabla_{\!x}\cdot\big(\,A\;\nabla_{\!x}\rho(x,t)\,+\,b(x,t)\;\rho(x,t)\,\big)$$
for $x\in\mathbb R^d$, $t>0$ and initial condition $\rho(x,0)=\nu(x)$ continuous such that $\nu\geq0$ and $\int_{\mathbb R^d}\nu(x)\,d x=1\,$.

Assume, e.g., that $b,\,\text{D}_x b$ have polynomial growth in $x$ uniformly in $t$.

I know that there exists a *weak solution* $\rho\in C(\mathbb R^d\!\times\!(0,\infty))$:
$$\int_{\mathbb R^d}\! \phi(x)\,\rho(x,t)\,d x -\! \int_{\mathbb R^d}\! \phi(x)\,\nu(x)\,d x \,= \int_0^t \!\!\int_{\mathbb R^d}\! \big(\nabla_{\!x}\!\cdot\!(A\nabla_{\!x}\phi(x))-b(x,s)\cdot \nabla_{\!x}\phi(x)\big)\,\rho(x,s)\, dx\, ds$$
for $t>0$ and $\phi\in C^2_c(\mathbb R^d)$.
Can I conclude that $\rho\in C^{2,1}(\mathbb R^d\!\times\!(0,\infty))\cap\, C(\mathbb R^d\!\times\![0,\infty))$ ?

I cannot find results about the regularity in classical sense of solutions of these parabolic PDEs. Bogachev, Krylov, Rochner, Schaposhnikov in their book "Fokker-Planck-Kolmogorov equations" study the measure solutions of these (and much more general) parabolic PDEs, but I couldn't find such a result about regularity in classical sense.
Classical results like Friedman "Partial differential equations of parabolic type" instead seem to deal only with bounded coefficients.

Comment: Regularity results for parabolic PDEs are local, so I am not sure what the issue is (just multiply your equation by a cutoff function). Existence and bounds at infinity are a more serious problem. As you say, textbook results are always for bounded coefficients, while most physical applications have unbounded coefficients. What is usually done is approximate by problems with bounded coefficients and derive uniform estimates.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy could you please write an answer or provide some reference? It is not clear to me how to elaborate your hint of multiplying by a cutoff function

Comment: @MichaelRenardy where precisly should I multiply by a cutoff function? I've tried to multiply either the coefficient $b$ or the solution $\rho$ but I don't manage to conclude